# Cordova / Phonegap "jquery cordova.oauth2.js" , Function makeAPICalls not defined

Tags: android, jquery, facebook, api, cordova

I am new in Stackoverflow, and still learning in develop cordova app. i have trying to find the above question on google and stackoverflow, but dont find any clue.

I am making a hybrid app (framework7) which user can login using their facebook account. i am successfully to get token from facebook using cordova plugin from [https://github.com/krisrak/jquery-cordova-oauth2][1], but it failed on function makeAPICalls . i have some questions :
1. where i can find the function makeAPICall ? 
2. do i need to include the facebook sdk javascript on the app ?
3. How to retrieve the user data profile and image ?

Here the script

```
    $.oauth2({
    auth_url: 'https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth',
    response_type: 'token',
    client_id: 'XXXXXX',
    redirect_uri: 'http://localhost:8100/',
    other_params: {scope: 'basic_info', display: 'popup'}
}, function(token, response){
    makeAPICalls(token);
}, function(error, response){
    alert(error);
});
```

Thank you.